# Trouble accessing elements in jQuery, callback not calling

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the Obj function called below, everything works except when after I load a file to the form class, the callback function that is supposed to add a class to the first p element in the bar div doesn't take place and add the class.

I should note that the html below where the classes are supposed to get added is a hbs template on the DOM.

Any advice on why this class doesnt get added?

```
var iterator = 0;
//creates object that gets sent to api
function Obj(name, vale) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevents pg refresh

    $('.form').load(quest[iterator], function () {
        if (iterator == 0) {
            console.log('c')
            $('.bar p:first-child').addClass('enter');
        }
        else if (iterator >= 2) {
            $('p.enter:last-child').next().addClass('enter');
        };
    });
    //loads next html question to page
    switch (name) {
    case null:
        break;
    case 'state':
        vale = usStates[stateConvert(vale)];
        data[name] = vale;
        break;
        //if its the state, we convert the state name to abbrievation
    default:
        data[name] = vale;
    }
    //move array accessor up to next question
    iterator++;
}
```

```
<div class="bar">    
    <p id="income" onclick="redo(0, this.id)">Income</p>
    <p id="state" onclick="redo(1,this.id)">State</p>
    <p id="rent"onclick="redo(2,this.id)">Rent</p>
    <p id="zip" onclick="redo(3,this.id)">Zip Code</p>
    <p id="roommate" onclick="redo(4,this.id)">Room mate</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `event` is not a global variable (except in Internet Explorer), you need to pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: `$('p.enter:last-child').next()` will never select anything. If it's the last child, there can't be a next element after it.

Comment: Do you see `c` in the console?

Comment: I dont see the C, also theres not any p.enters to begin with, so thats why the first part is adding the enter class to p. Then the 2nd part is finding the last child p element WITH the ENTER class

Comment: That's not what `:last-child` means. Your selector matches all `p` elements with the `enter` class that are also the last child of their parent.

Comment: Your HTML is calling the `redo()` function, not the `Obj()` function.